# Improving mysql query performance

Tags: mysql

I am running a mysql query of the following form  which is taking quite a bit of time to complete:

```
select distinct(column_name) 
from table where date(DateVal)="2013-06-18" 
and column_name IN (select distinct(column_name) 
                    from table 
                    where date(DateVal)="2013-06-17");
```

Is there a better and more performant way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JOINS are (in my experience) more efficient than IN-queries. Also check that you have your indexes set up right.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.column_name
FROM MyTable a 
JOIN MyTable b ON a.column_name = b.column_name
WHERE DATE(a.DateVal) = '2013-06-18' AND DATE(b.DateVal) = '2013-06-17'
```

Comment: But a JOIN query will not necessarily return the same thing as the `IN` query.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That's new for me. Can you provide an example? Always willing to learn ;)

Comment: See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a9aa3/1  (And btw: `distinct` is ***NOT*** a function. It always operates on *all* columns in the select list. Parentheses around the column will not change that)

Comment: In this case the query with JOIN will give the same result. It will also help a lot if you convert `DATE(a.DateVal) = '2013-06-18'` to `a.DateVal BETWEEN '2013-06-18' and '2013-06-18 23:59:59` (or the equivalent thing using `>=` and `<`).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Of course, that makes sense. But the distinct already solves that problem in this situation. Thanks anyway for the example.

Comment: From my point of view the `distinct` does not "solve" the problem. It is merely a workaround for the fact that the query fetches far too many rows in the first place

Comment: @Vatev: if the JOIN query and the IN query are equivalent a good query optimizer should notice and both queries will have the same performance (not sure if MySQL is smart enough though)

Comment: In my exprience, MYSQL has a stupid optimizer, in this case join is faster than IN().

Comment: MySQL is not known for its optimizer smartness... It this case it is not smart enough to realize the result is the same.

Comment: Refer to here http://spin.atomicobject.com/2011/03/25/mysql-in-query-performance/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name no but also PostgreSQL will most likely give an better Query Execution Plan with JOIN vs IN.. MySQL optimizer sometimes makes wierd plans..

Comment: @Jungsu Heo the best SQL optimizer is still the human brain with 33 petaflops.. if you understand the engine you can make it run with the correct qeuries.. and your reference only makes sense when t1.a and t2.b are PRIMARY/UNIQUE keys if not you need to use an DISTINCT the remove duplicates because IN also is doing this..

Comment: @RaymondNijland First of all. sorry my bad English. I agree with reference link. a_horse_with_no_name said that "both queries will have the same performance (not sure if MySQL is smart enough though)", so I want to let him know about IN() v.s. JOIN of MySQL. He was supposed be Oracle (or something better than MySQL) user. BTW "if you understand the engine you can make it run with the correct qeuries" it sounds like i don't know about optimizer.

Answer (score 0):

**EXISTS faster than IN**

I think Peter's query is faster than IN. BUT Have you try this? Below query also produces same results with your and peters.

```
select column_name
from table x
where date(DateVal)="2013-06-18" 
  and EXISTS  (select 1 from table where date(DateVal)="2013-06-17" AND column_name = x.column_name)
```

**date(DateVal) can't use INDEX**

Btw, even if "DateVal" is indexed column, you cannt use index. If it is a DATETIME column

```
DateVal BETWEEN '2013-06-18 00:00:00' AND '2013-06-18 23:59:59'
```

Above Can use index.

Also I think there should exist INDEX(DateVal, column_name) to make it index scan.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe also consider indexing the DateVal column

How about this?

```
declare @RecentDateVal datetime
declare @PreviousDateVal datetime
declare @Cnt int

Set @RecentDateVal = "2013-06-18"
Set @PreviousDateVal = "2013-06-17" 

select @Cnt = count(column_name) from table where DateVal=@PreviousDateVal
select if(@Cnt > 0,select distinct(column_name) from table where DateVal=@RecentDateVal,null)
```